# Armv8 Assembly cmp freezes at runtime

Tags: assembly, neon, armv8

I have already posted a similar code here, but now my problem is different.
For some reason, if I try to compare x3 with x4 the application freezes at runtime, but if I compare x3 with x2 it works just fine and returns the content on x4 (43520/1010101000000000)

I just can't wrap my head on what is happening, there should be no big difference between comparing x2 and x4. There must be something (probably simple) that I am missing.
Maybe I did something wrong while dealing with memory of registers?
What is that, that after applying the `and    x4,x2,x5`  instruction and saving on x4, that makes it different from x2? For what I know, the only difference should be the upper bits, if any.

```
   ASM_FUNC(REV16)
    
      ldr    x1,=oneHundredSeventy//Loads the memory address of "oneHundredSeventy" variable into the x1 register
      ldr    x2,=empty_variable   //Loads the memory address of "empty_variable"  variable into the x2 register
      mov    x3,#43520            //Moves the expected result to x3
      mov    x5,#4294967295       //filter 0b0000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111
        
      LD1   {V0.16B},[x1]         //Loads the value from the memory address saved on x1 to the V0 neon register
      REV16  V1.16B, V0.16B       //Reverts the bits on the V0 neon register and saves on the V1 neon register 
                                  //This instruction splits the 128-bit V1 register into eight 16-bit containers
                                  //divided into two sub containers of 8-bits                  
      MOV    x2,V1.D[0]           //Set x2 to the value of the first double word in V0
    
      and    x4,x2,x5             //Eliminates the upper bits on the x2 register
     
      cmp    x3,x4                //Compares the value of x4 and x3  
      b.ne   Neon_rev16_error     //if different, go to test_error
      b      Neon_rev16_end       //if equal, go to test_end
        
    Neon_rev16_error:
      mov    x0,x4                //Loads the value on x4 to the return register (x0)
      ret
    
Neon_rev16_end:
  mov    x0,#0                //Loads the value #6 to the regurn register (x0
```

This is the C code that calls it

```
int main(void)
{
  long int fff = REV16(); //it calls the function in assembly, starts the entry point
  print(f"REV16 %lu \n",fff);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What OS? How does it "freeze"? What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: @Jester I am using UEFI. So it runs pre OS. Unfortunately, I don't have a debbuger. It runs normally when I compare x3 and x2

Comment: Oh yay, fun. This doesn't look like it depends on anything, so have you tried running it under an OS with a debugger?

Comment: @Jester, that is the only platform I have to run armv8 codes :/ 
Do you see anything weird in the code? Or just like me thinks this should work just fine?
I am open to any other suggestions of how to eliminate the upper bits on x2

Comment: @Jester, thanks. I managed to make it work